# laravel redirect to route when user is logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

i am a beginner in laravel, i am trying to redirect to another route if the user is logged in, the signup and login are working perfectly and are not a problem, but when i try to do

```
@if(Auth::check())
    {{
        redirect()->route('news')
    }}
@endif
```

the redirect script gets output on the screen like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found Cache-Control: no-cache, private Location: http://localhost/red-sec/public/news <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8" /> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost/red-sec/public/news" /> <title>Redirecting to http://localhost/red-sec/public/news</title> </head> <body> Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost/red-sec/public/news">http://localhost/red-sec/public/news</a>. </body> </html>
```

Please excuse me if i did a rookie mistake  i am extremely new to laravel, and the news route is set up correctly and is working

EDIT 1:
for the first comment, yes, here is my web.php file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');

Route::post('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as' => 'signup'
]);

Route::post('/signin', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',
    'as' => 'signin'
]);

Route::get('/news', [
    'uses' => 'userController@getNews',
    'as' => 'news',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

Comment: is the route actually named news? i.e. in your routes file, do you have something like `Route::get('/news')->name('news')`?

Comment: i edited the question please check the web.php file yes it it

Comment: it seems to be generating the redirecting script correctly but it is printing it out on the screen

Comment: One small thing I noticed is that `UserController` is not capitalized correctly on the `/news` route... but I also have a question, how come redirect the user within a blade file and not within `UserController` somewhere? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am checking in my welcome view (route name is home) if the user is logged in, if they are i want them to redirect them to the news route

Comment: fixed the typo thanks but it was working before the typo was noticed either way. my only problem is redirecting

Comment: here is an image of what it looks like http://prntscr.com/e7x04w

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't try to (and can't) redirect in views. Views should be ONLY used to display data, not to do business logic.

Because you are not using controller to do any logic (you return view directly from router), you can do something like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if(Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->route('news');
    }

    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');
```

Text displayed in your view is actually a HTTP response.

Comment: oh ok so in the web.php file ? but i don't want it to always redirect to news if the user is logged in, only on the welcome page

Comment: The easiest way would be to add this check to home controller.

Comment: ok so i need to create a home controller ? but i dont have a home model. do i need a home model ?

Comment: beat me by 20 seconds! haha

Answer (score 2):

so I'm assuming you want to see if they're already logged in, and if they are you want to redirect them away from the login page? You could accomplish that in a `Route::get('/signin')` method on `UserController`. Before it returns the signin view you could do `Auth::check()`, and if that is true, then do the `redirect()->route('news')`

You should note, however, that Laravel ships with a ton of authentication scaffolding already in place, [which you can read about here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication)

In your `web.php`, have this take the place of the `/` route:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
  if (Auth::check()) {
     return redirect()->route('news');
  }
  else {
    return view('welcome');
  }
}
```

Comment: i see, but the login page is also the main page. i want to redirect away from the main page to news if the user is logged in

Comment: so what you're saying is that in `welcome.blade.php` you have a login form, and if the user is already logged in, you would rather redirect them to `/news` where you can return a  `news.blade.php` view?

Comment: that is exactly it